# How can I return a Sequence?

Tags: return-value, sequence

Recently I had the need to redefine a certain symbol in my init.m so it would be automatically omitted from any lists it appears in. I decided to redefine it to an empty sequence, e.g. `Locked = Sequence[]`, but that got me thinking. What if I wanted to return a sequence (not necessarily an empty one) in a `:=` definition? `Return` doesn't have the `SequenceHold` attribute, and adding it in a package might cause problems, so what would I do?

**EDIT:** I think I've figured out what exactly causes me to have the problem. I've defined it to display a `Message` first to let me know whenever a package I'm importing attempts to "attack my computer". (It *is* trying to cause my computer to behave in a manner not consistent with my wishes, after all.) So I defined it as `Locked := (Message[Locked::nope]; Sequence[])`, but strangely it just returns Null. (It doesn't show a return value, but if I do `{Locked}`, it returns `{Null}`, and if I try to set it as an attribute it says that Null  is not a valid attribute and doesn't set any of them.)

Comment: `Locked` is itself `Locked` in version 9, precisely to prevent people doing what you are trying to do here, which is the oldest trick in the book. ;) About the question, though: `Return` is rarely needed and you can anyway return results wrapped in any head that is either `SequenceHold` or `HoldAllComplete` to achieve what you want. I'd suggest `Unevaluated` as a reasonable choice, useful also for its habit of disappearing.

Comment: Yes, I know `Locked` is locked in Mathematica 9, which is precisely why I keep a copy of Mathematica 8 installed on one computer. I believe I've tried using Unevaluated. Do you mean something like `Return[Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]`? If not, could you please give an example of what you do mean?

By the way, take a guess what I used to prevent packages from erasing my definition of Locked. ;-)

Comment: I mean, look at the answers below--nobody is using `Return`. It's really only necessary when you want to bail out of a construct like `While` that ordinarily wouldn't have any return value, or which wouldn't terminate except in the case of a manual return. If you encounter such a situation then `Return@Unevaluated@Sequence[...]` is indeed fine (though you might need the second argument of `Return`). Otherwise, just use `Unevaluated@Sequence[...]` in place of the usual return value (typically the last position of constructs such as `CompoundExpression` or `Module`).

Comment: Re: your edit... what's the problem with `Unevaluated@Sequence[]` in this case? Incidentally if you consider the use of `Locked` to be malicious then I might suggest that the best course of action is not to use such packages in the first place. We have discussed this issue here before and the community concensus was that it harms us all to openly discuss how to circumvent `Locked` or `Encode`. Given the way this discussion is going, I would suggest removing that context or otherwise the question is likely to be deleted.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with `Locked := (Message[Locked::nope]; Sequence[])`, as as OleksandrR. mentioned, `Locked` is `Locked`, but note that in your code `Sequence[]` occurs inside `CompoundExpression`, which does not have `SequenceHold`, so it is immediately removed, which is probably also not what you intended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Calculate the `List` of results you wish to return and use `Apply` to replace the head:

```
listFn[a_, b___] := If[a > 0, {b}, {0}];
seqFn[args___] := Sequence @@ listFn[args];
f[1, seqFn[2, 3, 4, 5], 6]
f[1, seqFn[-2, 3, 4, 5], 6]

(*--> f[1, 3, 4, 5, 6] *)
(*--> f[1, 0, 6] *)
```

Here `listFn` represents the calculation of the results and does not need to be a separate function.  The particular example above can be written more simply as

```
seqFn[a_, b___] := Sequence @@ If[a > 0, {b}, {0}]
```

**Edit**

It should be stressed that the method assumes `listFn` actually evaluates to the `List` of desired inputs; if not, the `Head` of the expression returned will be replaced with `Sequence`, perhaps with undesired results.  In such a case, a method such as @Jens's may be used.

For instance if `a` is non-numeric, say a `Symbol`, in the example above, then you get

```
f[1, seqFn[x, 3, 4, 5], 6]
(*-> f[1, x > 0, {3, 4, 5}, {0}, 6] *)
```

Often one can construct a `List` of the actual results, though.  (With thanks to @Mr.Wizard.)

Comment: That's the easiest way, I think.

Comment: This worked great for me. Thanks a lot! Accepted.

Comment: There is a problem with this method.  Apply `(@@)` is used whether or not `If` evaluates, therefore if you enter `x =.; seqFn[x, 1, 2, 3]` you get `Sequence[x > 0, {1, 2, 3}, {0}]` which is wrong and confusing.  You could force `If` to evaluate using `TrueQ` or the fourth argument but it would often be better if delayed evaluation was possible, as is the case with many built-in functions.  To that end it's better and shorter to write: `seqFn[a_, b___] := If[a > 0, ## &[b], {0}]`.  Now `seqFn[x, 1, 2, 3]` returns `If[x > 0, (##1 &)[1, 2, 3], {0}]` which is correct if `x` acquires a value later.

Comment: @flarn See my caveat above before you put this into use.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Good point.  I should probably stress in the answer that one has to have actually calculated the `List`.  See edit.

Comment: +1 now that the warning is included in the answer

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 12):

Here is one idea:

```
Clear[sf, mySequence]

sf[x_] := If[x > 0, mySequence[8, 9], 0]

mySequence /: (h : Except[If])[x___, mySequence[y___], 
  z___] := h[x, y, z]

f[1, 2, sf[1], 4]

(* ==> f[1, 2, 8, 9, 4] *)
```

So I defined a `sf` function that returns the sequence as the result of an `If` statement. This is just an example, illustrating the general scenario that the result  will be returned by some evaluation of the form `returningHead[...,mySequence,...]`.

What gets returned is *not* a `Sequence` but instead an inert wrapper `mySequence`, which will be converted into a `Sequence` by the definition following `mySequence /:` - the only restriction being that I don't want it to be converted when it's in the last expression of my function, whose head was `returningHead` (specifically `If` in this example). In all other cases, `mySequence` will be converted to `Sequence`, as is illustrated by the last line.

**Edit**

The advantage of this wrapper approach combined with `TagSetDelayed` (the `/:` definition) is that you then have more fine-grained control over *when* `mySequence` gets delivered as a sequence. For example, you may be calling `sf` from inside a `List` as in the above example, but sometimes from inside a function `f2` that can't deal with sequences. Then you can add `f2` to the list in the `Except` statement to avoid errors in the processing of `sf`, until its output gets placed into the correct context.

Comment: Cool, that's a good idea. I'm just surprised it doesn't have a much simpler method built in. Thanks! :-)

Comment: Maybe there is a simpler method - you may want to wait before accepting this answer to give others some motivation to chime in...

Comment: Okay, I unaccepted it. Sorry, but you *did* basically ask me to. Of course, if nobody else posts a simpler method I'll be sure to mark it as accepted again.

Comment: That's perfectly fine!

Comment: I have sometimes needed that sort of control.  Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe I've missed the point, but a sequence in most ways is just another *Mathematica* expression, so consider just returning  a sequence.

```
f[args___] := args
g[x, f[a, b, c], y]
```

> g[x, a, b, c, y]

```
g[x, f[], y]
```

> g[x, y]

#### Update

I have edited this answer to incorporate Mr. Wizard's observation that `args` in `f[args___] := args` is already a sequence and doesn't need to be wrapped with `Sequence`.

Comment: This can be written more simply: `f[args___] := args`.  `Sequence` is *automatically* applied to the raw sequence `args` if no surrounding head is found.  The advantage of Jens' method over either of these is in the case of `SetAttributes[g, SequenceHold]`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this seems more native to me than Jens's, and I vote this as the obvious #1 answer. That advantage doesn't seem big to me given that symbols with `SequenceHold` probably have that attribute for a reason. Furthermore, it could be in some cases less than the disadvantage of giving other upvalues the chance of "winning". Finally, there's also the possibility to do what Jens did but straight with `Sequence`, say `Sequence /: (h : Except[If])[b___, HoldPattern@HoldPattern@Sequence[m___], a___] := h[b, m, a]`

Comment: @Rojo I like this one too but I have been holding my vote hoping that Mr. Goldberg would amend his answer to use or at least include the shorter syntax I proposed. :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. I made the change. I would have done it before except that I felt your comment counted as change :-)

Comment: The change that you made is not what @Mr.Wizard meant mainly, hehe

Comment: @Rojo. You're right. I misread what he wrote. Up too late I suppose. However, if I rewrite my answer his way, it's not really my answer any more. Of course, it would be better.

Comment: Oh no, it *is* your answer, it just has a bit of terse-style syntax tweaking from me.  +1 :-)

Answer (score 3):

*I hardly ever use this kind of stuff anymore, but here are some ideas*

**SetDelayed**

To return a sequence using a function defined by `SetDelayed`, simply try

```
seqFu[] := Sequence[]
```

Or even

```
Clear[seqFu]
seqFu[args___] := Sequence[args];
```

There is a trap that you should be wary of here. The following may seem to work as expected

```
seqFu2[args___]:= Unevaluated[args]

seqFu2[1,2]
```

> ```
> Sequence[1,2]
> ```

but the following does not produce a sequence

```
seqFu2[1]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

**Other**

You can also create sequences on the fly. Sometimes `Unevaluated` is useful for this. For example, you can do

```
CompoundExpression[args, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
```

> ```
> Sequence[]
> ```

Or

```
Identity[Unevaluated[Sequence[]]]
```

> ```
> Sequence[]
> ```